# C# Read file and join lines

Tags: c#, file

I have a file and I am trying to join the first and second rows into one row.
This is the file:
EDIT:

```
P09\tNone
21\tMAIN\t\0"
```

Comment: LastOrDefault gets second row?

Comment: just read the file sequentially, one line at a time.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question: please state why.

Comment: The point is, the file has a line split into two lines.  I need a way to retrieve both line (1 and 2, 3 and 4 etc) into one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Take()`:

```
string[] lines= { "A", "b", "c" };

IEnumerable<string> firstTwoLines = grades.Take(2);
```

---

To answer your question:

```
foreach (string columName in string.Join(",", lines.Take(2)).Split(delimts.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)){}
```

Comment: Does `IEnumerable<T>` have `Split` method?

Comment: This is for the columns, and the rest?

Comment: @LiviuM I used your code for join the columns and work perfect but still not get how to join the data: foreach (string cells in lines.Skip(0))
            {
                var cell = cells.Split(delimts.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (cell.Length <= dt1.Columns.Count)
                {
                    dt1.Rows.Add(cell);
                }
            }

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (string line in lines)
    foreach (string columName in line.Split(delimts.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
    }
```

Also you can use `SelectMany` LINQ feature:

```
foreach (string columName in lines.SelectMany(_ => _.Split(delimts.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
{
}
```

Comment: Of course, this code takes all lines, not two, I just thought `both==all`